# Saving attachments to local folder

Tags: vba, outlook

i'm trying to solve an issue that is popping up when running a code to save attachments to a local folder. Below the error message, which translated is saying: Error -2147024891 (80070005) during execution: Cannot save the file. You are not authorized for this folder.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtH7y.png)

When looking for the error this following appears:
[error message 2][2]

The funny thing is, until a certain point last month i was able to run the code and as far as i know there was no change in authorization. Does anyone have a clue where i can find the solution?

Comment: What is the actual file path passed to the `SaveAsFile` method?

Comment: Are you able to create any file in the same folder manually?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the folder specified in the Excel worksheet exists on the disk?

In your code it is not clear what is the actual file path is passed to the `SaveAsFile` method. First of all, I'd recommend making sure a valid file path is provided as a parameter in the code, for example:

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
 Dim saveFolder As String
 Dim dateFormat
 
 saveFolder = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Saved\"
 For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Eugene, with your feedback i was able to solve the issue. It indeed was the file path!